# Switch to another running application from terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Let's say I have opened Firefox Browser and Libre Office, and then I opened Terminal. Can I, from Terminal use a command to switch back to Firefox.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it using `wmctrl`. To install it use in terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

To switch to firefox use the following command in terminal,

```
wmctrl -a firefox
```

Actually it switch to a window with name containing 'firefox' in it. see [`man wmctrl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/wmctrl.1.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks...It's Working, Now I need figure out to switch based on Processed ID of Java Swing Application.